# Bash: replace 4 occourance of a string if exist

Tags: bash, sed

I have a string that is sometimes

```
xxx.11_222_33_44_555.yyy
```

and sometimes

```
xxx.11_222_33_44.yyy
```

I would like to:
Check if has 4 occourances of `_` (figured out how to do it).
If so - remove string's `_33` (the `33` string changes, can be any number), so I am left with `xxx.11_222_44.yyy`.

Comment: can you add expected output for both input samples? the current expected output is contrary to description

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using sed :

```
sed 's/\(_[0-9]*\)_[0-9]*\(_[0-9]*_[0-9]*\)/\1\2/'
```

It matches the four underscores and replace the whole by the needed parts.

Test run :

```
$ echo "xxx.11_222_33_44_555.yyy" | sed 's/\(_[0-9]*\)_[0-9]*\(_[0-9]*_[0-9]*\)/\1\2/'
xxx.11_222_44_555.yyy

$ echo "xxx.11_222_33_44.yyy" | sed 's/\(_[0-9]*\)_[0-9]*\(_[0-9]*_[0-9]*\)/\1\2/'
xxx.11_222_33_44.yyy
```

Answer (score 0):

perhaps something like this

```
echo "xxx.11_222_33_44.yyy" | sed -e's/\.\([0-9]\+\)_\([0-9]\+\)_\([0-9]\+\)_\([0-9]\+\)\./.\1_\2_\4./'
```

which checks if there are 4 groups of numbers separated by `_` between the two dots and if yes, it leaves out the third group

Answer (score 0):

try this;

```
echo "xxx.11_222_33_44_555.yyy"  | awk -F'_' 'NF>4{print $1"_"$2"_"$4"_"$5};'
```

Comment: note you can set `OFS` as well and say `awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="_"}NF>4{print $1, $2, $4, $5}'`. This way, `awk` will automatically glue fields together using `_` instead of you having to hardcode them.

Answer (score 0):

Solution using `perl` and Lookahead and Lookbehind

```
$ a="xxx.11_222_33_44_555.yyy"
$ perl -pe 's/\.\d+_\d+_\K\d+_(?=\d+_\d+\.)//' <<< "$a"
xxx.11_222_44_555.yyy
```